# Is this topology metrizable?

Tags: general-topology

Is the irrational sequence topology metrizable?

The irrational sequence topology is generated by the clopen basis 
$$
\big\{\{x\}\,:\,x\,\text{is irrational}\big\}\cup\big\{A_n(x) \cup \{x\}\,:\,n\in\mathbb{N}\,\text{if}\,x\,\text{is rational}\big\},
$$ 
where $A_n(x)$ is a tail of a sequence $x_n$ of irrational numbers that converge to $x$. (In this topology, we fix a convergent sequence for every rational number).
I proved that this space is $T_4$, but I couldn't prove that this space is not $T_5$ or $T_6$, so that it cannot be metrizable. Can someone give me a hint?

Comment: My thoughts after looking at this for a moment (a few seconds): This space is clearly not second countable, so if it happens to be the case that the space is not separable (and you can show this), then (you can show that) it can't be metrizable.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro: I don't understand. There are lots of non-second-countable non-separable metric spaces.  The metric hedgehog space of spininess $\omega_1$ would be one example.

Comment: @Arthur Fischer: You're correct. I misstated what I wanted to say, and should have written *if it happens to be the case that the space is separable*. (For metric spaces, second countability is equivalent to separability.)

Comment: @Arthur Fischer: Unfortunately (after thinking for another moment), unless I'm missing something, the uncountable collection of irrational singleton open sets prevents the space from being separable.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro: Sorry, I was working on my solution below.  Yes, as each irrational is isolated, any dense subset must contain all irrationals, and so the space cannot be separable.

Answer (score 3):

The space is metrizable.  For this I will make use of the Nagata-Smirnov Metrization Theorem:

> A topological space $X$ is metrizable iff it is regular and has a $\sigma$-locally finite base.

(A family of subsets of a topological space is called

- *locally finite* if each point has an (open) neighbourhood which meets only finitely many sets in the family.
- *$\sigma$-locally finite* if it is a countable union of locally finite subfamilies.)

First let $Y = \bigcup_{q \in \mathbb{Q}} A_0 ( q )$, and $Z = \mathbb{R} \setminus ( \mathbb{Q} \cup Y)$.  Note that $Z$ is a discrete clopen subseteq of $\mathbb{R}$, and $Y$ is countable.

- For each $q \in \mathbb{Q}$ and $n \in \mathbb{N}$ let $\mathcal{B}_{q,n} = \{ \{ q \} \cup A_n(q) \}$.
- For each $y \in Y$ let $\mathcal{B}_y = \{ \{ y \} \}$.
- Let $\mathcal{B}^\prime = \{ \{ z \} : z \in Z \}$.

It is clear that each $\mathcal{B}_{q,n}$ and each $\mathcal{B}_y$ ($y \in Y$) is (locally) finite.  Note that as for each $q \in \mathbb{Q}$ the set $\{ q \} \cup A_0(q)$ is an open neighbourhood disjoint from $Z$, it follows that $\mathcal{B}^\prime$ is locally finite.

Therefore $$\mathcal{B} = \bigcup_{q \in \mathbb{Q}} \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \mathcal{B}_{q,n} \cup 
\bigcup_{y \in Y} \mathcal{B}_{y} \cup 
\mathcal{B}^\prime$$ is a $\sigma$-locally finite base for $\mathbb{R}$.

As you have shown that the space is normal (and hence regular) it follows that it is metrizable.

(Nagata-Smirnov is surely overkill, but I'm not seeing a more direct proof at the moment.)

---

***Gaaack!!***

There is a way to get this result using much weaker tools.  Note that the space is the topological sum of $Z$ and $Y \cup \mathbb{Q}$, so it suffices to show that each of these subspaces are metrizable.  Clearly $Z$ is metrizable since it is discrete, so all that remains is $Y \cup \mathbb{Q}$.  For this we make use of Urysohn's Metrization Theorem:

> Every second-countable regular (Hausdorff) space is metrizable.

It is easy to see that the irrational singletons together with the basic open neighbourhoods of the rationals forms a countable base for the subspace $Y \cup \mathbb{Q}$, and as regularity (and Hausdorffness) was already established, we're done!